# Modifications of app after submission

Tags: iphone, xml

Sorry I am super newb', I would like to know what is the best way / what is feasible in terms of updating the content of an iPhone application, in the following case:

- application has been submitted and approved
- i need sudden change of text in one of the section
- i need sudden change of image in one of the section

My first idea is to create a XML feed somewhere on a server for that particular section, and update from there, am I right? If so, what prevents me from putting some porn images in there? Just putting myself into Apple shoes :)

Thanks!
XL

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.

Apple might pull your application if you update with porn though.

And make sure you don't impact users without a data connection.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you'd upload an update to the App Store.

You can also, update plist or database content over the Internet using XML, JSON, images, or text files, etc, no problem. More maintenance required though to keep track of content changes for each clients of there are any dependencies.

But both will work.

If Apple sees porn, or customers flag your App, bye-bye developer license.

Comment: Thank you Jordan! This could lead to difficult situation: you have a client with content X, display the RSS feed, then suddenly that feed starts playing different content (client changed to "boobs" without telling you), then you get blamed for this...